# Encrypt field value in LINQ-to-sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, encryption, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to take a better encryption approach for the functionality of

```
Person.FirstName = Encrypt(rawFirstName);
Person.sensitiveInfo = Encrypt(sensitiveInfo);
```

I'd rather not have to manually encrypt this kind of data every time it's used, so I've looked into modifying the .dbml and the Person object found in the .designer file.

I've come up with this:

.dbml file:

```
<Column Name="FirstName" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(256) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
```

.designer.cs file:

```
public partial class Person : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _FirstName;

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_FirstName", DbType="VarChar(256) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return Decrypt(this._firstName);
        }
        set
        {
            if (Decrypt(this._firstName) != value)
            {
                this.OnFirstNameChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._firstName = Encrypt(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanged("FirstName");
                this.OnFirstNameChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing now is that it works inside the program(I've logged the before/after values in `set` to make sure), but will actually save the *unencrypted* values to the database. It looks like the storage `_FirstName` variable isn't being saved to the database as I thought, but the `get` method is being used instead.

I've taken a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868156/encrypt-column-data-with-linq) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106271/encryption-of-a-fields-value-in-a-linq-to-sql-entity), but I can't for the life of me exactly figure out what they're trying to get across with the protected vs internal variables. Is there something simple I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a partial class for the generated class.  The field stored in the database should be FirstNameSecure, LastNameSecure, etc.

Then in the partial class create the properties FirstName, LastName, etc that will encrypt/decrypt their secure version.

Comment: How can I map the FirstNameSecure field in the database to use the partial class? Do I modify the Name/Member attributes in the .dbml file?

Comment: Change the name in the database to FirstNameSecure and then create a new file that contains the partial class with the definition of FirstName.

Comment: It took me 3 months to figure out what you were saying, but I finally get it. Thanks.